# Future of native-client after WebAssembly Post-MVP

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient, webassembly

I am sure after WebAssembly Post-MVP, asm.js will be deprecated. Even now, a few existing asm.js projects already start to use WebAssembly. JS engine (V8) also starts to comiple asm.js to WebAssembly, so even if old projects never migrate, end-users will still get partial advantages from WebAssembly.

My question is, what about native-client then? It is not implemented in JS engine so that can be a problem. Native-client seems to be deprecated even now. Will native-client be completely removed from Chrome in foreseeable future? I would love to see some reduction in binary size of Chrome.

Side questions:

- After thread/gc/simd/exception are included in WebAssembly, is there still something native-client has but missing in WebAssembly (blocking migration)?
- It took WebAssembly about 2 years just to reach MVP, what is the expected time for any one of the Post-MVP to get finalized?
- It seems like WebAssembly group is tackling multiple Post-MVP features at once instead of one by one, won't that make it slower to finalize one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the side-questions only, because I no longer work on Native Client. Google's plans are its own to speak for, so I'll make this a wiki.

**Update** as of 2017/05/20 [NaCl isn't in glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=42a844c6a213f9219a4baa013c7305679d5dcaaa). This was the original libc which was supported, and took quite a while to clean up and upstream. It was only ever supported by NaCl's GCC toolchain. There's still support for musl libc, which works with the more up-to-date LLVM-based NaCl and PNaCl toolchain.

**Update** as of 2017/05/30 the Chromium team announced [the fate of PNaCl](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/05/goodbye-pnacl-hello-webassembly.html) and [tentative roadmap of WebAssembly features](https://wasmdash.appspot.com/).

Here are some Native Client features which you haven't mentioned:

- Out-of-process, which many consider a bug because it forces asynchronous communication. It allows guaranteed address space, which with 64-bit isn't much of an upside, and was critical to Native Client's double-sandbox design. WebAssembly doesn't have processes yet.
- Has blocking to and from the JavaScript event loop, through `postMessageAndAwaitResponse`. Also seen as a bug by many.
- Has many APIs through [Pepper](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable). Many mirror the web platform's APIs.
- Can do memory protection through `mprotect` (though execute pages are limited).
- POSIX signals can be handled.
- Supports computed `goto` and other irreducible control flow.
- Has some Just-in-Time code patching support.
- Supports weaker than `seq_cst` atomics.
- Has support for inline assembly, as long as it follows the NaCl validation rules.

Not all of these are in Portable Native Client, though. There's [official documentation of differences](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/nacl-and-pnacl).

There's no timeline for any of the post-MVP WebAssembly features. We don't want to rush anything, but we want to deliver one the most useful things first. It's a community group, so priorities are really driven by whoever gets involved. Implementations won't be able to tackle features all at once, but exploration parallelizes well.